# Why does a Python bytearray work with value >= 256

Tags: python, binary, byte

The Python [documentation for bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) states:

> The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <=
>   x < 256.

However the following code suggests values can be >= 256. I store a 9 bit binary number which has a maximum value of: `2^9-1 = 512-1 = 511`

```
ba = bytes([0b111111111])
print '%s' % (ba)
```

The 9 bit binary number is printed as decimal 511:

```
[511]
```

I don't know what the intended behavior is, but I *assumed* the most significant bit(s) would be dropped to give an 8 bit number.

Comment: What version of python are you using?  The code in your example gives a `ValueError` in 3.3.1

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I would assume it's 2.x. Since the `print` statement

Comment: @MooingRawr OPs linked doc is for 3.1

Comment: Huh...... it first linked to 2.7 for me my apologys (might have looked at the wrong tab....)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't actually creating a `bytearray` or a `bytes` object, you're just creating a string containing `'[511]'`, since `bytes` in Python 2 is just a synonym for `str`. In Python 3, you *would* get an error message:

```
ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)
```

The following code works in Python 2 or Python 3; note that I'm passing an 8 bit number, so it's in range.

```
ba = bytearray([0b11111111])
print(repr(ba))
```

**output**

```
bytearray(b'\xff')
```

Comment: Also if you type `help(bytes)` in Python 2 it shows the `str` help page.

Comment: So according to the error message `ValueError: byte must be in range(0, 256)`, the value 256 is allowed as well as value 0. This makes 257 possible values in a byte. Python always impresses me...

Comment: @RustyGear No, `range(0, 256)` produces 256 numbers, from 0 up to 255. Similarly, `"abcdef"[0:3]` is the string `"abc"`. Almost everything in Python uses that convention.

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
a = 511
byte = a.to_bytes(byte length goes here, 'little')
```

to decode:

```
a = int.from_bytes(byte, 'little')
```

Comment: thanks,it's work.and
byte = (-511).to_bytes(2, 'little', signed=True)
can Solve signed type